# Can we get a unique candidate (that might fail) for the algebraic semantics of a logic by intersecting all the congruences that respect implication?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can we get a unique candidate (that might fail) for the algebraic semantics of a propositional logic by intersecting all the congruences that respect implication (in the sense that they respect $\vdash \varphi \to \psi$ and $\vdash \psi \to \varphi$)?

I've been trying off and on for a little bit to understand the construction of an algebraic semantics in Blok and Pigozzi's *Algebraizable Logics*.

I'm trying to come up with, via brute force, a construction for producing a semantics (henceforth called the *naive semantics*) given an arbitrary consequence relation $\vdash_S$ that *always succeeds even if $\vdash_S$ is very badly behaved*.

My goal is doing this is to do understand what the actual notion of an *algebraic semantics* is. If I defined the notion of the naive semantics correctly, it **will be the same as the true notion of the algebraic semantics for a given logic, except for the fact that it's always defined even $R$ is not a congruence.** **The only reason that I am talking about the naive semantics and algebraic semantics as if they are separate things is because I don't understand the real notion of an algebraic semantics.**

**My question is threefold.**

- **Does this construction work? The part I am most skeptical of is intersecting the congruence relations.**
- **Is the naive semantics equivalent to the algebraic semantics when the latter exists?**
- **This construction will always give us exactly one designated truth value. Does that mean that there are legitimate algebraic semantics that we miss?**

---

Here are the rules for being a consequence relation, paraphrased from pages 5 and 6 of *Algebraizable Logics*.

If $\varphi \in \Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$.

If $ \Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$ and $\Gamma \subset \Delta$, then $\Delta \vdash_S \varphi$.

If $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$ and it holds for all $\psi$ in $\Gamma$ that $\Delta \vdash_S \psi$, then $\Delta \vdash_S \varphi$.

If $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$, then there exists some finite subset $\Gamma_0$ of $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0 \vdash_S \varphi$.

Let $\sigma$ be a substitution. If $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$, then $\sigma\Gamma \vdash_S \sigma\varphi$.

---

Let $L$ be a propositionial logic whose signature consists of at least $\{\top, \to\}$. Let $\top$ be both a propositional constant (zero-place connective) and a distinguished wff within $L$.

Let $\vdash_S$ be a consequence relation on $L$. $\vdash_S$ is constrained to make $\vdash_S \top$ hold (i.e. $\top$ is always a tautology).

Let $R$ be a two-place relation on $L$. Let $\langle \varphi, \psi \rangle \in R$ iff $\vdash_S \varphi \to \psi$ and $\vdash_S \psi \to \varphi$. $R$ is necessarily symmetric, but is not necessarily reflexive or transitive or a congruence with respect to the signature of $L$. These latter conditions would require *additional conditions on $\vdash_S$ that $\vdash_S$ being a consequence relation does not promise us.*

Let $\mathrm{Cong}(L, L)$ be the set of binary relations on $L$ that are congruences with respect to the connectives of $L$ (i.e. each connective (such as $\land$) is identified with its syntactic function ($x, y \mapsto x \land y$)).

I define the relation $S$ as follows.

$$ S = \cap \{ z : z \in \mathrm{Cong}(L, L) \;\text{and}\; R \subset z \} $$

This is always well-defined because the full relation $L \times L$ is always a congruence.

$S$ is always a congruence because the lattice of congruences of an algebra is a complete lattice. (I cite [page ten](https://people.math.rochester.edu/grads/caten2/2020ua/7.pdf) of this presentation by Charlotte Aten). I could be misapplying the result though. (I think that result is stronger than what I need, since my logic $L$, thought of in a universal algebra setting, only has a signature and no axioms. (I think.))

So, assuming that I didn't make a mistake and $S$ actually is well-defined, we can define the naive semantics as follows.

It is a model $N$ (for naive) defined in the following way.

The universe of $N$ is the set of equivalence classes of $S$.

For each connective $\land$, the interpretation of $\land$ is computed by taking an arbitrary member of each equivalence class given to $\land$ as argument (say $a$ and $b$) and then determining the equivalence class of $a \land b$.

The sole designated truth value of $N$ is the equivalence class of $\top$.

Our $N$ gives us a shiny new semantic consequence relation $\vDash_N$, which may or may not line up with $\vdash_S$. Ideally, I'm hoping that $\vDash_N$ is equivalent to $\vdash_S$ if and only if $N$ is the actual *algebraic semantics* of $\vdash_S$ exists.

Comment: What do u mean "(naive semantics) will be the same as the true notion of the algebraic semantics for a given logic, except for the fact that it's always defined even R is not a congruence."? In Blok's paper abstract they mentioned "A deductive system S over a language L is algebraizable if there's a quasivariety K such that the S-consequence relation and the equational consequence relation are interpretable in one another... then S has precisely one equivalent algebraic semantics..." And the congruence relation (1) therein is essential to get any quotient (Tarski-Lindenbaum) algebra...

Comment: I'm trying to understand the equational algebraic semantics construction ... and am trying to come up with something slightly more general that removes all constraints on $\to$. I think in the equational algebraic semantics construction described in the book, you take the set of all well-formed formulas and mod out by $\varphi \equiv \psi$ (which is $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$). A necessary condition for this is $\equiv$ being a congruence wrt all the connectives (which I think you don't get for free).

Comment: The biconditional is a standard logical equivalence as formalized by their relation (1). For your congruence generalization to other connectives, say, $\lor$, can you formalize your idea how to get your desired congruence from $\phi \lor \psi$ interpreted in the so called "naive" semantics?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\leftrightarrow$ as an abbreviation. In the construction in my question, the relation $S$ that I'm building is constrained to be a congruence with respect to the syntactic functions associated with the connectives ($x, y \mapsto x \land y$ and $x, y \mapsto x \lor y$ and others). I think this is well-defined. In my construction, all the connectives, $\to$ included, are treated the same way when we're constructing $S$.